# Is there a proof that $x^{y+k} > (y+k)^x$ for $k>0$ with $x<y$ and $x^y > y^x$

Tags: logic, exponentiation

I've come across this observation when I was trying to solve a programming task and I was wondering if there's a proof for it. I tried proving it myself but lacking a proper mathematical education I haven't really got anywhere. The statement is as following:

Given two natural numbers $x$ and $y$ with $x < y$ and $x^y > y^x$, $x^{y+k} > (y+k)^x$ is true for every $k > 0$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  MathJax commands are no effective unless they're enclosed on `$` signs.  `$x^2$` shows up as $x^2$.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for editing! I didn't know about the proper way to format my mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take logarithms.
$$x^y>y^x\iff y\log x>x\log y\iff \frac {\log x}x>\frac {\log y}y$$
and similarly,
$$x^{y+k}>(y+k)^x\iff \frac{\log x}x>\frac{\log(y+k)}{y+k}$$
so we consider the function $f(t)=\frac{\log t}t$ where $t>0$.

A little calculus shows that $f$ increases from $-\infty$ to $\frac1e$ on $(0,e]$ and then decreases to $0$ on $[e,\infty)$.  So, if $x<y$ and $f(x)>f(y)$ it must be that $y>e$.  Then if $z>y$, we have $f(x)>f(y)>f(z)$.

Take $z=y+k$.

Here's a [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20log%28x%29%2Fx%2C%20x%20from%200%20to%20100) of $f(t)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I needed a while to fully understand it but now it makes sense. Great explanation!

Comment: @nikstffrs My pleasure.